Sharing reviewers’ comments with all reviewers when a manuscript is rejected?
Imagine the following, very common case: A manuscript was submitted to a journal. The editor sent it to two to three reviewers. The review forms are ready and sent back to the editor. The final decision is to reject the manuscript.
Now, what should the editor (or whoever is handling the review process for that specific manuscript) do next?
In my years as a reviewer for several journals, I found there are two policies:

The editor shares the decision letter (that includes the comments from all reviewers) with everyone (i.e., authors and reviewers).
The editor sends the decision letter to the authors only.

I can think of many reasons to support Policy 1, and can not think of any good reason for Policy 2 (except maybe an alleged confidentiality violation?).
Reasons why Policy 1 is the best option in my opinion:

It adds openness and transparency to the process (everyone sees all the comments – and their justification – not only from the reviewers but also from the editor).
Not only do authors learn from reviewers, but reviewers learn from each other. Win–win.
It is not uncommon that people send the same manuscript (many times disregarding reviewers’ comments) to the next journal, and also it is not uncommon that the same reviewer has to review the same manuscript. In these particular cases, a reviewer can also benefit from other reviewers’ comments in past submissions.

I checked the policies and FAQs, etc. of a number of major journals and publishers and did not find anything that explicitly says what they do. Also, many of them fail to follow Policy 1 in spite of repeatedly mentioning commitments to openness, transparency, and good practices in peer review. I find it a bit surprising that I didn’t find anything on this, so I assume I am not searching in the appropriate places or something is escaping my understanding of openness and transparency.
Therefore I ask reviewers out there: What are the pros and cons of sharing the rest of reviewers when the manuscript is not accepted? The question applies to rejected manuscripts but also to cases of major revisions, etc. where the final outcome is still unclear.
Additionally, I wonder if other reviewers/editors have had this situation before and if you know of any official guidelines and justification to follow either way.

I removed the initial constraint of this only being about rejections, as you later say that this is also for major revisions. I would have preferred the question to focus on one case, but since the existing answer addresses both, I consider this ship to have sailed.

In my experience as a reviewer I receive a letter reporting the editor's final decision - accept or reject - with a "thanks for your work". Sometimes that's a bcc of the letter to the author, which might contain some of the editor's reasons for rejection.
I have never seen other reviewers' comments. Not during the review process, nor after.
In answer to the OP's question, which is whether I should see those reviews, I think not.

As a counterpoint, I’d be hard-pressed to find a paper I’ve reviewed for which I didn’t see the reviews, either as soon as mine was in, or with the editor’s decision.

@Ethan Bolker would you mind elaborating on why you think you should not see the other reviewers' comments?

Yes, but...
Most reviewers are well-meaning, but sometimes things go wrong. Perhaps they fundamentally misunderstand the paper, or get hung up on some perceived issue that is tangential to the point of the paper. Sometimes they turn out to be lazy, rude, or just plain stupid.
So, one aspect of the editor's job is to act as a filter between authors and reviewers. Occasionally that might involve removing part of a review before the authors see it; more commonly, the decision letter might indicate that the authors do not need to put too much effort into addressing certain aspects of the review.
It would make the editor's job much harder if their critique of the reviews is then immediately sent back to the reviewer - who has probably done their best to be helpful, and invested several hours into trying to help the editor, for free. Apart from being offended, the reviewer may then feel compelled to try and engage the editor in further discussion about the issue to 'explain' their views.
OK, you say - let's give the editor two boxes to write in: they can give a general decision that is shared with everyone, and then a confidential set of comments that only go to the authors. But that just adds to the workload and complexity for everyone involved, for no obvious gain.
More generally, sharing the decision and reviews with the reviewers would almost certainly lead to some reviewers seeking to reopen the process: comments on the decision, criticism of points made in other reviews, suggestions that occurred to the reviewer having read the other reviews. Suppose the reviewer writes back and says "I've read the other reviews and changed my mind - I think you should've given them a chance to revise the paper" - now what does the editor do?
Finally, there is a benefit in maintaining the independence of the different reviewers. If all reviews are shared after the first-round decision, the reviewers' opinions will influence each other, potentially affecting how they react to any revised manuscript. Again, you can invent work-arounds - maybe reviews and decisions should only be shared following a final decision? - but again it's adding complexity for very limited benefit.

I am a surprised by the last paragraph. In all journals I ever reviewed for, reviewers get to see all reviews from previous rounds when reviewing a revision. I can see several points for this, in particular that reviewers can understand changes happening in response to another reviewer and that reviewers can evaluate reactions to other reviewers, for which nobody knows whether they will review again (when the review is solicited). Are there journals/fields that do not do this?

@Wrzlprmft I'm fairly sure that I've only ever seen the other reviews to the extent that they are quoted by the authors in their response letter. In any case, I think there is a difference between seeing them in conjunction with the authors' responses and revisions, and seeing them in isolation.

@avid I have never, ever witnessed any of the things you mention in your second to last paragraph. Also, even if that happened, why is that a problem? In the (very unlikely) case that a reviewer changes her/his mind due to other reviewers, I would say great! Science has just advanced and we're closer to a consensus. If most reviewers are convinced about something then the editor's work is even easier.
